# update an image in SQlite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, blob

i am trying to update an image in SQlite database but it gives me an error:

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "[B@d3d70b2" (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE img set image=[B@d3d70b2
```

on this line:

```
    sdb.execSQL("UPDATE img set image=" + bytes + " WHERE id='" + i + "'");
```

i have searched on many websites but what i got is only how to insert an image.

These are the 3 queries which i am using to insert, get and update the image.

```
public void insertImage(byte[] bytes, int user){

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("image", bytes);
    cv.put("id", user);
    int a= (int)sdb.insert("img", null, cv);
    Toast.makeText(context,"inserted at "+a,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public byte[] getimage(int i){
    Cursor c1 = sdb.rawQuery("select image from img where id='" + i + "'", null);
    c1.moveToNext();
    byte[] b= c1.getBlob(0);
    return b;
}

public void update(byte[] bytes, int i) {
    sdb.execSQL("UPDATE img set image=" + bytes + " WHERE id='" + i + "'");
}
```

Note: `insertImage and getImage is working fine.`

Comment: **Worst practice**. Don't bloat your database with binary data. Store the **path**, instead.

Comment: ok but the binary data will require when i will save data on a server database.

Comment: Not necessarily. Just return the **URL** (which is the equivalent of a path).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to concatenate `byte[]` in a String, that code will basically try to insert `bytes.toString()` not `bytes`.

Try this instead:

```
public void update(byte[] bytes, int i) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("image", bytes);
    sdb.update("img", cv, "id=" + i, null);
}
```